# What precisely is a sub-flow of a G-flow (Hausdorff group G acting on a compact Hausdorff space X).

Tags: group-theory, dynamical-systems, topological-groups

I am starting some reading in topological dynamics, and have come across a 'minimal subflow' and 'the universal minimal subflow'. I understand portions of these definitions fairly well, but I have not been able to come across what the definition of a 'subflow' is in general. My best guess is that, for a Hausdorff group G acting on a compact Hausdorff space X, $\phi : G \times X \rightarrow X$, I should think a subflow is the top space X with the action of $H$ a subgroup of $G$ on X. However I am not sure; perhaps I should be taking subspaces of X instead.

I would appreciate if someone could point me to a reference with this definition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer found [in this paper](http://https:/https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0305241.pdf) on page 10:

> In general, a (non-$\emptyset$) compact, $G$-invariant
>   subset $Y \subset X$ defines a subflow by restricting the $G$-action to $Y$